# Spaces in menu after CTRL + A

Tags: html, css, spaces

Following is the code for the Menu:

```
<a href="../zahlavie/about.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">O Nás</a>
<a href="../zahlavie/vyvojary.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">Vývojári</a>
<a href="../zahlavie/podmienky.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">Podmienky</a>
<a href="../zahlavie/napoveda.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">Nápoveda</a>
```

http://postimg.org/image/tmbv7fmtz/ this is how it looks like

in style.css i have

```
a.zahlavie_odkaz{
   color: white; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   margin: 10px; 
   font-size: 13px
}
a.zahlavie_odkaz:hover{
   color: grey; 
   text-decoration: underline; 
   margin: 10px; 
   font-size: 13px
}
```

And if I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> it looks like this
http://postimg.org/image/3pi6utj6f/

How do I remove those white places where nothing is written?

Comment: that is probably the padding

Comment: but i have no padding in style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the line breaks between your `<a>` elements. So instead of:

```
<a href="../zahlavie/about.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">O Nás</a>
<a href="../zahlavie/vyvojary.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">Vývojári</a>
<a href="../zahlavie/podmienky.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">Podmienky</a>
<a href="../zahlavie/napoveda.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">Nápoveda</a>
```

Do this:

```
<a href="../zahlavie/about.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">O Nás</a><a href="../zahlavie/vyvojary.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">Vývojári</a><a href="../zahlavie/podmienky.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">Podmienky</a><a href="../zahlavie/napoveda.php" class="zahlavie_odkaz">Nápoveda</a>
```